# Why is are the dicts in this list of dicts empty?

Tags: python, python-2.7

As the title implies; I'm unsure as to why the dictionaries in this list of dictionaries are empty. I print the dictionaries out before I append them to the list and they all have 4 keys/values.

Please ignore the 'scrappiness' of the code- I always go through a process of writing it out basically and then refining!

Code:

```
import ntpath, sys, tkFileDialog, Tkinter
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

class Comparison:
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = ET.parse(file)
        self.filename = self.get_file_name(file)
        self.root = self.file.getroot()
        self.file_length = len(self.root)
        self.data_dict = dict()
        self.master_list = list()
        self.parse_xml(self.root)
        print self.master_list

    def get_file_name(self, file):
        filename_list = list()
        for char in ntpath.basename(str(file)):
            filename_list.append(char)
            if ''.join(filename_list[-4:]) == '.xml':
                return ''.join(filename_list)

    def parse_xml(self, tree):
        for child in tree:
            if tree == self.root:
                self.step_number = child.attrib['id']
            self.data_dict['Step'] = self.step_number
            if len(child.tag) > 0:
                self.data_dict['Tag'] = child.tag
            else:
                self.data_dict['Tag'] = ""
            if len(child.attrib) > 0:
                self.data_dict['Attrib'] = child.attrib
            else:
                self.data_dict['Attrib'] = ""
            if child.text is not None:
                self.data_dict['Text'] = child.text
            else:
               self.data_dict['Text'] = ""
            print self.data_dict
            print "Step: "+str(self.data_dict['Step'])
            try:
                print "Tag: "+str(self.data_dict['Tag'])
            except:
                pass
            try:
                for key,value in self.data_dict['Attrib'].iteritems():
                    print "Attrib: "+str(key)
                    print "Attrib Value: "+str(value)
            except:
                pass
            try:
                if len(str(self.data_dict['Text'])) > 0:
                    print "Text Length: "+str(len(str(self.data_dict['Text'])))
                    print "Text: "+str(self.data_dict['Text'])
            except:
                pass
            print ""
            print len(self.data_dict)
            self.master_list.append(self.data_dict)
            print self.data_dict
            self.data_dict.clear()
            if len(child) > 0:
                self.parse_xml(child)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    root.iconify()
    if sys.argv[1] != "":
        file_a = Comparison(sys.argv[1])
    else:
        file_a = Comparison(tkFileDialog.askopenfilename())
```

Comment: But this scrappiness is hard for us to understand. Specially when we do not even have a clue regarding what code is supposed to do?

Comment: Check your indents... they are not correct.

Comment: The indents are a result of pasting into SO and not in the code. And the code is the beginning of a small XML comparison script. Though I think it's rather easy to discern what the code does by simply reading it...

Comment: @AdamMitchell We don't care what the indentation problems are a result of - fix them. You also need to post a [mcve] instead of this wall of unexplained code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you mean this:

```
 print len(self.data_dict)
 self.master_list.append(self.data_dict)
 print self.data_dict
 self.data_dict.clear()
```

The `dict` is empty because *you clear it*. Everything is a reference in Python.

```
>>> d = {k:v for k,v in zip(range(5),'abcde')}
>>> id(d)
140199719344392
>>> some_list = []
>>> some_list.append(d)
>>> some_list
[{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e'}]
>>> id(some_list[0])
140199719344392
>>> d.clear()
>>> some_list
[{}]
>>>
```

If you want a copy to be appended, then you need to explicitely copy it. If a shallow copy will do, then simply use `your_dict.copy()`:

```
>>> d = {k:v for k,v in zip(range(5),'abcde')}
>>> d
{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e'}
>>> id(d)
140199686153480
>>> some_list = []
>>> some_list.append(d.copy())
>>> id(some_list[0])
140199719344392
>>> d.clear()
>>> some_list
[{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e'}]
>>>
```

Comment: I clear after appending it to `master_list`. Hence being unsure of why the dicts in the list of dicts are empty - the title of the question.

Comment: It's the *same dict*

Comment: But I don't edit the element of the list, I clear the dict. So I don't understand how it affects the element of that list?

Comment: They refer to the same object.

Comment: The element of the list *is the same dict*. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination @juanpa.arrivillaga, very helpful!

Comment: You're welcome! Just remember, *everything works like this in Python*. This is especially important if the object is mutable, because it will come back to bite you if you aren't careful.